# Ansible - HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway when using script with XMLRPC

Tags: ansible, rpc

I have this script, that connects to service via XMLRPC, like:

```
import odoorpc
odoo = odoorpc.ODOO(host, protocol=protocol, port=port)
```

Task from `yaml` file:

```
- name: Change Odoo admin user password
  ansible.builtin.script: "change-user-password \
    {{ secrets_odoo_init_user_passwords_file }} --ignore-failed-login \
    --host {{ ansible_host }} --port 443 --protocol jsonrpc+ssl"
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ app_user }}"
```

Call looks like this (from ansible logs):

```
<my-host> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt my-host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u odoo /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-lsrscdzqfzfliptrdleqjxcwaseuaggn ;  /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635367335.375884-2165879-123865031409885/change-user-password /opt/odoo/.secrets/odoo_init_user_passwords_file --ignore-failed-login --host my-host --port 443 --protocol jsonrpc+ssl'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
```

The full traceback is:

```
NoneType: None
fatal: [dev]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "stderr": "Shared connection to my-host closed.\r\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Shared connection to my-host closed."
    ],
    "stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635367335.375884-2165879-123865031409885/change-user-password\", line 109, in <module>\r\n    odoo = login(\r\n  File \"/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635367335.375884-2165879-123865031409885/change-user-password\", line 75, in login\r\n    odoo = odoorpc.ODOO(host, protocol=protocol, port=port)\r\n  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/odoo.py\", line 95, in __init__\r\n    self._connector = rpc.PROTOCOLS[protocol](\r\n  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/__init__.py\", line 288, in __init__\r\n    super(ConnectorJSONRPCSSL, self).__init__(\r\n  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/__init__.py\", line 211, in __init__\r\n    self._proxy_json, self._proxy_http = self._get_proxies()\r\n  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/__init__.py\", line 235, in _get_proxies\r\n    result = proxy_json('/web/webclient/version_info')['result']\r\n  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/jsonrpclib.py\", line 113, in __call__\r\n    response = self._opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 523, in open\r\n    response = meth(req, response)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 632, in http_response\r\n    response = self.parent.error(\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 561, in error\r\n    return self._call_chain(*args)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 494, in _call_chain\r\n    result = func(*args)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 641, in http_error_default\r\n    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)\r\nurllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway\r\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Traceback (most recent call last):",
        "  File \"/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635367335.375884-2165879-123865031409885/change-user-password\", line 109, in <module>",
        "    odoo = login(",
        "  File \"/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635367335.375884-2165879-123865031409885/change-user-password\", line 75, in login",
        "    odoo = odoorpc.ODOO(host, protocol=protocol, port=port)",
        "  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/odoo.py\", line 95, in __init__",
        "    self._connector = rpc.PROTOCOLS[protocol](",
        "  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/__init__.py\", line 288, in __init__",
        "    super(ConnectorJSONRPCSSL, self).__init__(",
        "  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/__init__.py\", line 211, in __init__",
        "    self._proxy_json, self._proxy_http = self._get_proxies()",
        "  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/__init__.py\", line 235, in _get_proxies",
        "    result = proxy_json('/web/webclient/version_info')['result']",
        "  File \"/opt/odoo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odoorpc/rpc/jsonrpclib.py\", line 113, in __call__",
        "    response = self._opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)",
        "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 523, in open",
        "    response = meth(req, response)",
        "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 632, in http_response",
        "    response = self.parent.error(",
        "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 561, in error",
        "    return self._call_chain(*args)",
        "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 494, in _call_chain",
        "    result = func(*args)",
        "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 641, in http_error_default",
        "    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)",
        "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway"
    ]
}
```

I read that people workaround this error by using `headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}`. But if I use `script` module via ansible, how can I specify such header?

**The thing is, I only get this error if I run script via ansible. I tried running that script explicitly from my machine and from target machine. In those cases, it works fine.**

```
ansible [core 2.11.6] 
  config file = /home/oerp/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/oerp/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/oerp/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/oerp/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/oerp/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) [GCC 9.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = True
```

**Update**

Turn out the problem when XMLPRC call is made, service is not yet running, thus the error.

So I have to use `RPC` only when service is already running.

I tried using `wait_for` like this (note, my Odoo service port is not exposed via compose, its only accessible through docker network by nginx):

```
- name: Save Odoo container status
  set_fact:
    odoo_ip: "{{ docker_compose_output.services.odoo.app_odoo_1.networks.app_backend.IPAddress }}"

- name: Wait for IP to be active
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ odoo_ip }}"
    delay: 1
    state: drained
```

I do get this error:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635403378.5625799-2174550-176521610555803/AnsiballZ_wait_for.py", line 100, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635403378.5625799-2174550-176521610555803/AnsiballZ_wait_for.py", line 92, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635403378.5625799-2174550-176521610555803/AnsiballZ_wait_for.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.wait_for', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.wait_for', _modlib_path=modlib_path),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_pic_t21b/ansible_wait_for_payload.zip/ansible/modules/wait_for.py", line 674, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_pic_t21b/ansible_wait_for_payload.zip/ansible/modules/wait_for.py", line 657, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_pic_t21b/ansible_wait_for_payload.zip/ansible/modules/wait_for.py", line 356, in __init__
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
fatal: [dev]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to my-host closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635403378.5625799-2174550-176521610555803/AnsiballZ_wait_for.py\", line 100, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635403378.5625799-2174550-176521610555803/AnsiballZ_wait_for.py\", line 92, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635403378.5625799-2174550-176521610555803/AnsiballZ_wait_for.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\r\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.wait_for', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.wait_for', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py\", line 210, in run_module\r\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py\", line 97, in _run_module_code\r\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py\", line 87, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_pic_t21b/ansible_wait_for_payload.zip/ansible/modules/wait_for.py\", line 674, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_pic_t21b/ansible_wait_for_payload.zip/ansible/modules/wait_for.py\", line 657, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_wait_for_payload_pic_t21b/ansible_wait_for_payload.zip/ansible/modules/wait_for.py\", line 356, in __init__\r\nTypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Its unclear what argument it is about.

Comment: I would guess you're chasing the wrong question, but since you asked about setting headers, [they have an example](https://github.com/OCA/odoorpc/blob/v0.7.0/odoorpc/odoo.py#L57-L63) in their repo of how to pass in a custom `opener` that can mutate the request as you like

Comment: Your "unclear message" is because you omitted the `port:` that it should wait for connectivity, [as seen in the examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#examples). It's a terrible error message, for sure, but the `int()` and `NoneType` are a dead giveaway

Comment: @mdaniel oh I didn't notice that `port` and `path` args were mutually exclusive, so one of those had to be specified. Because I don't expose port externally, I thought port won't be seen anyway, so didn't specify one. But it turns out that was the only thing I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the problem was that service (container) I was trying to connect with `RPC` was not yet running and that was causing bad gateway problem.

In my playbook, container is stopped and then started and just after initiating start, it tries to use `RPC`, which would fail (as my reverse proxy, which is nginx, would not yet see odoo service).

So simple fix is this:

```
- name: Pause for 3 seconds for Odoo service to load
  pause:
    seconds: 3
```

Though its not ideal as I can't be sure that I would need 3 seconds. It might be too long or too fast.

I tried using `wait_for`, but got some confusing errors. I think `wait_for` is better approach as it could react better than simple pause.

**Update**

Better way would be to use `wait_for`, so we don't need to specify specific delay time. Like (this way it waits till service is ready to be used):

```
- name: Save Odoo container status
  set_fact:
    odoo_ip: "{{ docker_compose_output.services.odoo.app_odoo_1.networks\
      .app_backend.IPAddress }}"

- name: Wait for IP to be active
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ odoo_ip }}"
    port: 8069
    state: started
```